# OAuth implementation for Qt test application

Tags: qt, oauth

I am learning OAuth to implement in my Qt application.I used [this](https://github.com/pipacs/o2) step by step documentation to have test app for twitter authentication.Here is the following code:-

```
 ox1 = new OXTwitter(this);

    ox1->setClientId("client-id");//Id got from twitter application created.
    ox1->setClientSecret("secret-key");//secret key got from application.
    ox1->setUsername("user-id");
    ox1->setPassword("password");

    connect(ox1, SIGNAL(linkedChanged()), this, SLOT(onLinkedChanged()));
    connect(ox1, SIGNAL(linkingFailed()), this, SLOT(onLinkingFailed()));
    connect(ox1, SIGNAL(linkingSucceeded()), this, SLOT(onLinkingSucceeded()));
    connect(ox1, SIGNAL(openBrowser(QUrl)), this, SLOT(onOpenBrowser(QUrl)));
    connect(ox1, SIGNAL(closeBrowser()), this, SLOT(onCloseBrowser()));
    ox1->link();
```

But i am getting the following error.I have already created a test app in twitter application and used the key in my code still i get this error any idea.

> OXTwitter::link O1:nTokenExchangeError: 202 "Error downloading https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token - server replied:
>   Forbidden" "Client is not permitted to perform this
>   action" Login has failed

Answer (score 0):

Its not the issue with the code.

If you're experiencing this issue, write to api@twitter.com from the email address associated with the application. Include the consumer key effected and the API policy team wil try to get you set back up as quickly as possible. When you get an email back from the automated system, be sure and reply to that email as well.